# Where's ServiceManager class in Android?

Tags: android, aidl

I saw a demo of simulateKeyInput,
some codes as following:

`final IWindowManager windowManager=IWindowManager.Stub.
asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("window"));`

But I can't find ServiceManager in package android.os,
maybe it's not in android SDK, does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a custom implementation of `ServiceManager` within your project or your projects included .jar files.

Else there is a `ServiceManager` in `javax.jnlp` => (Java Network Launching Protocol).. not sure if this is related to you & Android.

Comment: ThanQ for reply. I've found it in framework source and copy it to my project, it works and thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[android.os.ServiceManager](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/ServiceManager.java) in frameworks/base/core/java/